# Trigger wrapped C/C++ rebuild when instantiating a Julia "object" (that calls the wrapped C/C++ functions)

Tags: python, c++, matlab, julia, wrapper

I found the following paradigm quite useful and I would love to be able to reproduce it somehow in Julia to take advantage of Julia's speed and C wrapping capabilities.

I normally maintain a set of objects in Python/Matlab that represent the blocks (algorithms) of a pipeline. Set up unit-tests etc.

Then develop the equivalent C/C++ code by having equivalent python/Matlab objects (same API) that wrap C/C++ to implement the same functionality and have to pass the same tests (by this I mean the exact same tests written in python/Matlab where either I generate synthetic data or I load recorded data).

I will maintain the full-python and python/C++ objects in parallel enforcing parity with extensive test suites. The python only and python/C++ versions are fully interchangeable.

Every time I need to modify the behavior of the pipeline, or debug an issue, I first use the fully pythonic version of the specific object/block I need to modify, typically in conjunction with other blocks running in python/C++ mode for speed, then update the tests to match the behavior of the modified python block and finally update the C++ version until it reaches parity and passes the updated tests.

Evey time I instantiate the Python/C++ version on the block, in the constructor I run a "make" that rebuilds the C++ code if there was any modification. To make sure I always test the latest version of the C++.

Is there any elegant way to reproduce the same paradigm with the Julia/C++ combination? Maintaining julia/C++ versions in parallel via automatic testing.
I.e. how do I check/rebuild the C++ only once when I instantiate the object and not per function call (it would be way too slow).

I guess I could call the "make" once at the test-suite level before I run all the tests of the different blocks. But then I will have to manually call it if I'm writing a quick python script for a debugging session.

Let's pick the example of a little filter object with a configure method that changes the filter parameters and a filter method the filters the incoming data.

We will have something like:

```
f1 = filter('python');
f2 = filter('C++'); % rebuild C++ as needed

f1.configure(0.5);
f2.configure(0.5);

x1 = data;
x2 = data;

xf1 = f1.filter(x1);
xf2 = f2.filter(x2);

assert( xf1 == xf2 )
```

In general there will be a bunch of tests that instantiate the objects in both python-only mode or python/C++ mode and test them.

I guess what I'm trying to say is that since in Julia the paradigm is to have a filter type, and then "external" methods that modify/use the filter type there is no centralized way to check/rebuild all its methods that wrap C code. Unless the type contains a list of variable that keep track of the relevant methods. Seems awkward.

I would appreciate comments / ideas.

Comment: Why not just type `make` before you test? Also, I don’t see the point in keeping two implementations for an algorithm. Why do you trust a Python implementation more than a C++ implementation?

Comment: I understand that in case of Python/C++ you need Python for sanity control/debugging and C++ for performance. The whole idea behind Julia is that you just write the code once - it is both readable as Python and fast as C++.

Comment: The reason to keep both implementations is that the C/C++ is for embedded real-time customized proprietary chips. Occasionally I write assembly for them or use custom hardware accelerators that get added based on our needs (we control the chip design and the C/C++ compiler). The power of debugging/designing sophisticated signal processing algorithms in Matlab/Python is still unmatched in C/C++. Still Matlab and Python can be annoyingly slow sometimes when you have thousands of tests or you want to run live.

Comment: I'm hoping that if Julia gets mature enough I can get the best of both worlds. Fast prototyping, debugging with multiple interactive sessions / plotting capabilities etc, fast testing and strong live performance in Julia and easy wrapping of C/C++/Assembly code  for the embedded system. I don't see a Julia compiler being developed anytime soon for these embedded chips.

Comment: Notice how the same C/C++ can be compiled also on a PC/Cluster. I left some details out. In fact the process it: prototype in python/matlab, add tests, wrap C/C++, build for the PC/server, pass the same tests (run at every commit) on the PC/server, compile C/C++ for the custom chip, pass the same tests on the chip simulator (also wrapped in python/matlab), deploy to the actual chip, pass the same tests on the chip, now we are done.

Comment: @CrisLuengo hope it clarifies where I'm coming from.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel I'm familiar with Julia's origin / overall goal and I support it. But in my case I still need C/C++ and deeper control of the low level operations.

Comment: I'm not a Julia expert by any means, so examples if possible could speed up my understanding of the possibilities. Maybe using modules?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can't wrap your functions in a struct like this?

```
struct Filter 

    FilterStuff::String
    Param::Int

    function Filter(stuff::String, param::Int)

        # Make the C++ code here

        # Return the created object here
        obj = new(stuff, param)

    end

end
```